# Standardise font of Rich Text Area field in email

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page from which users can generate an email and a PDF, one of the fields is Rich Text so that users can paste in notes with bullet point, bold text etc.

The problem I have is that when generating the email, the rich text field comes through in the font pasted in, which is often different from the standard field font.

I've seen a few examples of stripping out the html using regex, but what I really want to do is maintain the bullet points etc but override the font type and size so that it matches the rest of the email.

Any ideas??

Comment: Given you don't want to mess with the markup users are pasting into your merge fields, have you tried adding an inline set of style tags to your email template, and setting a font-family,font-size etc with !important attribute to hopefully override the pasted styles ?

Comment: nice idea, but just ignores it unfortunately!

Comment: Regex just for font tags ?

Comment: Cheers - that's done the job! feel free to put as an answer

Comment: I havent done the hard yards - be great if you could post your resulting regex expression as an answer so others can benefit from your efforts :)

Comment: @paul, can you post the regex as an answer if you still have it?